# $$ajaxid is @none in a partial refresh

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I´m doing a partialrefresh on another div like this:

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet(idZusatzgeräte , { params: { 'keyValueFortabZusatzgeraete': paramValue}});
```

When I look into Chrome Network the partial refresh is executed. But there is no response from the request. Furthermore $$ajaxid equals to "@none". I found that if $$ajaxid is @none there will never be a response. Strange thing is that if I execute the partialrefresh from my console in my browser it works just fine.

Does anyone have a clou on how to disable this @none in the ajaxid?

Comment: Double check parameters of the event. Include source snippet, please.

Comment: Even if *$$ajaxid* is *none*, a response is sent back to the client.